# Limiting HTML Text bar to Only one Entry of Specific Characters

Tags: html, string, text

I currently have the code:

```
<td><input name="miles" type="number" 
       min="0" max="900" size="5" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g,'')"/></td>
```

This(`onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g,'')`) limits the user to only entering digits and periods. What I want to do, however, is make it so that the user can only enter one period, and after that, every other period will be deleted. Is this possible? Thank you for taking the time to read this post, and have a wonderful day!

Comment: Did you come up with a conclusion?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that! Thank you for the answer. I was so excited to implement it that I forgot to mark the question as answered haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accept only one period for input, you have to make it clear, **that the period should repeat once only**.

So this one may work in your case:

```js
^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

**NOTE:** You can check the details of every regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/BvCyjw/1).